# How to enable PUT and DELETE in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, http

I've been hunting for a while and can't seem to find how to enable PUT and DELETE in IIS7.  I keep getting 404s when I use those verbs.  I've played with request filtering, and that has no impact.  I've looked in IIS logs and I just see 404.0.  Any ideas?

More info: I'm using an HttpModule for REST URL re-writing.  So the handlers verbs won't cut it.

Update: OK -- so I figured it out.  I am using a module to re-write URLs and then a handler to process.  To get PUT and DELETE to work, I have registered the module as usual, and then explictly registered the handler for the PUT and DELETE verbs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a look at the "Handlers Mappings" sections at either the server or site level (IIS group). Select a mapping for an extension (e.g. .aspx) and select "Edit" from the context menu. The "Verbs" tab allows you to specify verbs to accept.

Comment: What extension, though? A REST transaction doesn't necessarily involve a file type, right?